# Using HTML form to update Oracle Database - Database Not Updating

Tags: php, sql, forms, oracle

I am attempting to create a form where an admin can update a webpage's data. I am taking the form's $_POST variables and sending them to the handler (in this case, UpdateInfo_SA.php). From there I am trying to send it to the database (see snippet 1). There is no error, in fact the page is blank (which is expected, given the current code). However, the table does not update.

Info:

Table Name: LOGISTICS_SLIDESHOW

Updating OH_RECORDABLE_ENERGY to any value (just to test to see if this works) where LOGISTICS_UPDATEID=0 (this represents the first column of the table).

Snippet 1 (Form Handler - UpdateInfo.php):

```
<?php
    require_once("mcl_Oci.php");
    $objConnect = oci_connect("user", "pass", "(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=HOST)(port=1533))(connect_data=(service_name=SID)))")
    $strSQL = "UPDATE INTOXDM.LOGISTICS_SLIDESHOW ";  
    $strSQL .="SET OH_RECORDABLE_ENERGY = '6'";  
    $strSQL .="WHERE LOGISTICS_UPDATEID= 0 ";
    $objParse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);  
    $objExecute = oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);?>
```

Snippet 2 (Form - SA_Update.php):

```
<?php

    $objConnect = oci_connect("user", "pass", "(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=HOST)(port=1533))(connect_data=(service_name=SID)))");

?>

<div align="center">
    <span style="font-size:60px";>
        <u>Update Page<br></u>
        Schedule Adherence: OH Contractors<br>
    </span>

<form method="post" action="UpdateInfo_SA.php">
    <span style="font-size:30px;">
        <u>Total YTD:<input type="number" name="SA_ytd_total" value="%"><br>
        Total MTD:<input type="number" name="SA_mtd_total" value="%"><br>
        Energy YTD: <input type="number" name="SA_ytd_energy" value="total"><br>
        Energy MTD: <input type="number" name="SA_mtd_energy" value="total"><br>
        Hydraker YTD: <input type="number" name="SA_ytd_hydraker" value="total"><br>
        Hydraker MTD: <input type="number" name="SA_mtd_hydraker" value="total"><br>
        NG Gilbert YTD: <input type="number" name="SA_ytd_gilbert" value="total"><br>
        NG Gilbert MTD: <input type="number" name="SA_mtd_gilbert" value="total"><br></u>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

As you can tell, the server is using php's to communicate with itself and the database. Thanks for any help you can give, it is very appreciated!!

Comment: There is no error, in fact the page is blank (which is expected, given the current code). In fact this need to show us the error, right? try first put it on top of your main php file error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);, and post the results editing your question.

Comment: The page is still blank. The connection is correct, I have checked by placing an incorrect table name and it errors saying that the table does not exist. When I put a correct table name, no error. When I put a wrong user/pass, it errors saying invalid user/pass. At first it error'd saying "invalid function oci_logoff()". I noted the oci_logoff line and nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: I didn't use oracle, just mysql, but the logic is simple, i guess the own oracle has a way to retrieve his own errors. Works like this: The php are working good, sending good request to oracle, if oracle got a internal error, if you didn't programmatic get it by forcing checking if was error, he don't do it by itself. Try to get errors from oci_* , i just didn't know exactly how do it because it's not my pratice.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into how to force error check @oracle.

Comment: Do you `commit` the transaction ? Only then the updated data is available to the rest of world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you `commit` the transaction in your php, where open up the connection and update ?

Unless `autocommit` is turned *ON* or you `commit` ,the updated data is not available to the rest of world

EDIT: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.oci-execute.php

The above link refers to the auto commit options available. Default is NO auto commit.. So all updates are rollbacked when the session is disconnected.

Comment: I found the answer, and will post it tomorrow when I am able to (has to be 8 hours after posting for me). I just had to remove the OCI_DEFAULT line. Very odd to me, but it works.

Comment: As per doc [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.oci-execute.php), That means my guess was right. OCI_DEFAULT means no auto commit. When you remove it, the session is auto commited before exit!!